# How to Sort WooCommerce products by ACF value?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

How is it possible to sort `WooCommerce` products by `Advanced Custom Field` values?

I've added some custom fields to the back-end and front-end of the website. The front-end implementation in my `functions.php` looks like so:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'tmy_eventbooking', 20 );

function tmy_eventbooking() {
    if( !empty( get_field('datum') ) ) { // if your custom field is not empty…
        echo '<p class="acf-info">Findet statt am: <span>' . get_field('datum') . '</span></p>';
    }
        if( !empty( get_field('datum_ende') ) ) { // if your custom field is not empty…
        echo '<p class="acf-info">Bis: <span>' . get_field('datum_ende') . '</span></p>';
    }
        if( !empty( get_field('veranstaltungsort') ) ) { // if your custom field is not empty…
        echo '<p class="acf-info">Ort: <span>' . get_field('veranstaltungsort') . '</span></p>';
    }
    return;
}
```

This works fine.

Now I would like to be able to sort products by these ACF fields (type `date` and `text`).

If a user clicks for example on a 'date' button or selects a location from a dropdown menu, all events get sorted accordingly. Events are regular `WooCommerce` service products.

What is a good way to approach this?

Comment: On which page you want to sort products?

Comment: On the products archive, where all products are displayed.

Comment: and how did you add the dropdown?

Comment: The dropdown is the default WooCommerce menu which you get on every product archive or category (and so on) page. I didn't change anything about it. EDIT: I removed the image because it might be misleading. What I meant to say is, I'm trying to implement sorting via ACF for users, so that they can sort products by date or location.

Comment: Yes but you must have to add the date and location option into the dropdown first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use two filter hooks to perform custom sorting in the archive page based on ACF.

> Use `woocommerce_catalog_orderby` filter hooks to add custom `date`
> and `location` options.

```
// Add these date and location sorting options on the frontend.
function add_new_custom_postmeta_orderby( $sortby ) {
    $sortby['date']     = __( 'Sort by date', 'woocommerce' );
    $sortby['location'] = __( 'Sort by location', 'woocommerce' );
    return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_new_custom_postmeta_orderby' );
```

> Use `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` filter hook to modified
> `orderby` and `order` based on option you choosed

```
function add_custom_postmeta_ordering_args( $sort_args ) {
    $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );
    switch( $orderby_value ) {
        case 'date':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num';
            $sort_args['order']    = 'desc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'date';
            break;

        case 'location':
            $sort_args['orderby']  = 'meta_value';
            $sort_args['order']    = 'asc';
            $sort_args['meta_key'] = 'location';
            break;
    }
    return $sort_args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'add_custom_postmeta_ordering_args' );
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [custom-sorting-options-ascdesc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/custom-sorting-options-ascdesc/)

Comment: Thank you! I have the sorting options by date and location in the drop down menu. But when I click them, I don't get the correct search results. For testing I have one product with ACF filled in. But I see all products in the search results.

Comment: it depends on what type of value you store in ACF.

Comment: They're type 'text' for the location and 'time/date' for the date.